# JSF bundle loading failure

Tags: java, tomcat6, icefaces, jsf-1.2

Currently my JSF (1.2) application produces the following failure during the start of the Servlet Engine (Tomcat 6.0.32)....

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.faces.Messages, locale de
    java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.faces.util.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:177)
    com.sun.faces.util.MessageFactory.getMessage(MessageFactory.java:136)
    com.sun.faces.util.MessageUtils.getExceptionMessageString(MessageUtils.java:351)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:187)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
    com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:230)
    com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:69)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
    javax.faces.component.ValueExpressionValueBindingAdapter.getValue(ValueExpressionValueBindingAdapter.java:70)
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.Alias.computeEvaluatedExpression(Alias.java:113)
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.Alias.make(Alias.java:137)
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBean.makeAlias(AliasBean.java:357)
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBean.makeAlias(AliasBean.java:342)
    org.apache.myfaces.custom.aliasbean.AliasBeanTagHandler.applyNextHandler(AliasBeanTagHandler.java:90)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
    com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
    com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DFaceletViewHandler.java:274)
    com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
    com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
    com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
    com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:52)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    de.konsens.wwwkmv.security.KmvExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(KmvExceptionTranslationFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

I have configured a message bundle in the faces-config.xml file

```
<application>
  <view-handler>com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
  <locale-config>
     <default-locale>de</default-locale>
     <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
     <supported-locale>de_DE</supported-locale>
   </locale-config>
   <message-bundle>Messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

I have put the property file into WEB-INF/classes/ folder (Messages_de.properties, Messages_de_DE.properties) but i always get this message....the most mysterious thing is that i only changed things in the configuration reading of the application but didn't change things in faces-config.xml or jspx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name javax.faces.Messages, locale de
> ```

This is actually a misleading exception and a bug in error reporting of older JSF 1.2 versions. The *real* problem is that the `<message-bundle>` cannot be found.

You mentioned that you placed `Messages_de.properties` and `Messages_de_DE.properties` in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder, which is fine, but you should *also* supply a default `Messages.properties` file. It can be kept empty.

Another possible cause is that you're *actually* developing using an IDE and that you placed it literally in the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder by the IDE navigator. You should not do this. This will be overriden whenever you build and deploy the WAR. Instead, you should place the `.properties` files in the source root of the project, there where all your Java packages also are.

Comment: I have added the Messages.properties to the /WEB-INF/classes folder and made the build out of the IDE on command line and the WAR file contains correctly the mentioned files. But the failure doesn't fade a way...

Comment: So, the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the build WAR file **do** contain those files? Well, then the problem is caused elsewhere. It's case sensitive, are you sure that you specified the right filename? If that's not it; what JSF impl/version exactly are you using? If you're unsure, extract JSF impl file by some ZIP tool and read the `Implementation-Version` entry of its `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file

Comment: Now i've solved in pragmatically and put a Messages.properties file into javax/faces location which solved the problem. (Not good but it works). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message :

```
20-09-2012 16:20:31   HTTP JVM: Can't find resource for bundle javax.faces.Messages, key nl. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in /prj/notes/appldata/data/domino/workspace/logs

20-09-2012 16:20:31   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: javax.faces.FacesException: Can't find resource for bundle javax.faces.Messages, key nl

20-09-2012 16:20:31   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in /prj/notes/appldata/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

Well, I'm using XPages (IBM's powerful RAD tool based on JSF) and in my case it was because the system wanted to **show some field-validation error messages**, when my `MessagesObject` was out of focus (or not even rendered).

I solved it at the source of the problem, because the error was due to a field-validation.
In fact, I was clicking on an image that switched to other dynamic content, by a partial refresh. I selected  "Do not validate or update data", so the field-validation was skipped.